# Getting error: "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string" in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is my query

```
Declare @last_run date; 
Declare @current_run date;

Set @last_run = 'SELECT CONVERT (date, ''2016-06-24'')';

Set @current_run = 'SELECT CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()) ';

Select 
    sh.isbn_l, sh.id_k, sh.id_s, sh.data, sh.quantity, l.price, 
from 
    Book as l
inner join 
    Sales as sh on l.isbn = sh.isbn_l
where 
    sh.timestamp between @last_run and @current_run
```

Comment: Max has given you the correct sql. To explain what you have done wrong: you declared a variable of type date. You attempted to initialize it to a string. Even though the string contained a sql statement, to the db engine it is just a string and it will not attempt to execute the statement it contains in order to assign it to your date variable. It seems you want to use dynamic sql in a situation where you don't need it and can not use it the way you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need those CONVERT statements in quotes.

```
Declare @last_run date; Declare @current_run date;
Set @last_run= CONVERT(DATE, '2016-06-24')

Set @current_run= CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME());
```